# Laravel Controller Subfolder

Tags: laravel

I tried to get the following curl statement work.
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/admin/user

In routes.php

```
Route::resource('admin.user', 'admin/UserController');
Route::get('/admin/user/{userid}', 'UserController@getAdminUser');
Route::get('/admin/user', 'UserController@index');
```

controllers/admin/UserControler.php

```
<?php namespace Controllers\Admin;
class UserController extends \BaseController {

public function index()
{  
     return DB::table('users')->get();  
}

public function getAdminUser($userid)
{  
     return DB::table('users')->where('userid', $userid)->get();             
}   
}
```

After I run the curl command, all list of user do not show up. Please give me advise.

Comment: And what is showing up ? What version on Laravel do you use? Have you set `debug` to `true` ?

Comment: can you see anything if you go to that url in the browser ?

Comment: I do not see anything.

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2. I set debug to true, but nothing shows.

Comment: It turned out I did not need to use subfolder. Thank you for all help.